# Mitsubishi FX PLC as OPC-UA client

Tags: automation, plc, industrial

I’m currently working on a project where a Mitsubishi FX PLC must function as a OPC-UA client.

Does anybody know if this is possible. And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a OPC-UA module FX5-OPC

Answer (score 0):

Mitsubishi FX PLC with FX5 OPC module can function as a OPC-UA Server, not client.
Thanks
Good luck